# Can Puppet File Source be from a web service?

Tags: http, puppet, puppetmaster, puppet-dashboard

Is there a (simple) way to have puppet use a file available on the internet for the Source property of a File?

eg:

```
file { "/home/text.txt":
  source => [
    "http://www.example.com/text.txt",
  ]
}
```

Comment: If you value the integrity of your servers, at least use https.  And use a more trustworthy domain cos you don't know who might be controlling that one... ummm...  It gets murkier from here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm writing an updated answer to notify future readers that now the File resource indeed implements the HTTP source.

From [the docs](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.7/reference/type.html#file-attribute-source):

> source
>
> A source file, which will be copied into place on the local system. This attribute is mutually exclusive with content and target. Allowed values are:
>
> - puppet: URIs, which point to files in modules or Puppet file server mount points.
> - Fully qualified paths to locally available files (including files on NFS shares or Windows mapped drives).
> - file: URIs, which behave the same as local file paths.
> - http: URIs, which point to files served by common web servers

So you can use the construct as you wrote it:

```
file { "/home/text.txt":
  source => "http://www.example.com/text.txt",
}
```

Comment: as of Puppet version 4.4.0 (via ticket https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-1072)

Answer (score 3):

It's been [requested as a feature](https://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/5783) for years... But you'd end up needing a custom function for this... or to use `curl` or `wget`. See [Puppet Forge](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/modules?utf-8=%E2%9C%93&sort=rank&q=wget).

What's in text.txt?

Comment: txt.txt is just an example. I actually want to use it to pull Freeradius clients from an admin system.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible out of the box right now:

> source:
>
> ...
>
> The available URI schemes are puppet and file. Puppet URIs will
>   retrieve files from Puppet’s built-in file server

I ended up using `define` I found on the internet:

```
define remote_file($remote_location=undef, $mode='0644'){
  exec{ "retrieve_${title}":
    command => "/usr/bin/wget -q ${remote_location} -O ${title}",
    creates => $title,
  }

  file{$title:
    mode    => $mode,
    require => Exec["retrieve_${title}"],
  }
}

remote_file{'/home/text.txt':
  remote_location => 'http://www.example.com/text.txt'
}
```